# Every method of installing unsigned printer driver has failed

Tags: windows-10, drivers, print-drivers

I have tried enabling nointegritychecks, testsigning, disabling driver signature enforcement through advanced startup, using gpedit.msc to enable using unsigned drivers. Nothing I have tried works, and the drivers I'm trying to use come from HP! The printer I'm using is a HP Deskjet F4400, although I don't think the printer matters much.

No matter what I do, I get the same ["The driver cannot be installed because it is either not digitally signed or not signed in the appropriate manner"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIhvG.png) error message. No amount of HP software can figure out what the problem is either, every installation software they have ever made just completely fails to either recognize the damn thing or do anything when it does.

Honestly, even if installing the driver does absolutely nothing for me, at least I'll have been able to do that much.

Comment: Actually the models matters. Your old printer DOESN'T need user installable drivers for modern Windows. Whatever you're trying to install is NOT for that model and NOT for that Windows version.

Comment: Then why does nothing recognize the printer? This isn't the first time I've had a driver issue like this, it's just the first time drivers sourced from the manufacturer have failed to install

Comment: There's NO drivers "sourced" from the manufacturer for Windows 10 (and old models), period. Why it isn't being recognized probably is the question you should be asking instead of making of fool of yourself with childish rants. In any case, as it happens with anything of that vintage, it may or may not work at all in currently supported Windows releases. If that's the case you may try a Virtual Machine for that purpose only. Of course, this after ruling out obvious problems like cables or the printer being faulty. You may want to try a mainstream Linux live session.

Comment: I already tried using a live debian session, it also only partially recognized the printer. I'm also a little exasperated here, I've been trying to get this to work for days. I don't think it's childish or foolish to write a tad passionately about a problem I'm having. You could have suggested using a virtual machine or using a linux live session in the first place and without being so rude about it. Also, the drivers litterally appeared after using official HP installation software. If that's not "sourced from the manufacturer" I don't know what is

Comment: Whatever drivers or installer you've tried is NOT FOR ANY CURRENT WINDOWS or even for some generations back that are already out of support (please read my answer). Do NOT insist is installing software that won't run in Windows 10 no matter what, period. It's either plug'n'play or you need to find yourself a comptible printer, end of story.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I'll try using a windows seven virtual machine. Why wouldn't the driver install though? Even if it wouldn't do anything I don't understand why I couldn't get it to install an "inappropriately signed" driver.

Comment: Precisely because it's a very old driver coded way before Microsoft started enforcing signed software. And since Windows 10 version 1607 it  tightned such requirements making such installations impossible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/kernel-mode-code-signing-policy--windows-vista-and-later-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The latest software released for HP Deskjet F4400 dates back from 2011** - link purposedly NOT provided so it won't lead other users astray - and that was a PATCH, not even a full driver, for Windows 7 upgraded from Windows Vista.

Yes, that's how old the hardware is. Even back in the Windoows 7 days it was already "plug'n'play", i.e., there were NO user installable drivers for Windows for that madel. It either worked or it wouldn't, end of the story.

You may get lucky with a mainstream Linux (e.g. Ubuntu, Debian, Manjaro, etc.) as it may have kept native support for older hardware whereas Windows dumped it uncerimoniously. Try in a live session first. It, or a much less safer old Windows version, can then be installed in a Virtual Machine for the exclusive purpose of running that old printer.